# Mysql: Filter table depend on subtring from column in different table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables in my DB.

1- Customers table.

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+
| customers | CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customers_phone_index` (`phone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+-----------+--------------------------------+
```

===> Data Example in customers table

```
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
| id | name                                   | phone           |
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 1  | Frehiwot Teka                          | (251) 988200000 |
| 2  | Fanetahune Abaia                       | (251) 924418461 |
| 3  | Yonatan Tekelay                        | (251) 911168450 |
| 4  | EMILE CHRISTIAN KOUKOU DIKANDA HONORE  | (237) 697151594 |
| 5  | MICHAEL MICHAEL                        | (237) 677046616 |
| 6  | ARREYMANYOR ROLAND TABOT               | (237) 6A0311634 |
|  7 | Edunildo Gomes Alberto                 | (258) 847651504 |
|  8 | Walla's Singz Junior                   | (258) 846565883 |
|  9 | sevilton sylvestre                     | (258) 849181828 |
+----+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

2- Countries table.

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+
 countries | CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `numcode` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `phonecode` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=254 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+-----------+--------------------------------+
```

===> Data Example in countries table.

```
+----+----------------+---------+-----------+
| id | name           | numcode | phonecode |
+----+----------------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | Cameroon       |     120 |       237 |
|  2 | Ethiopia       |     231 |       251 |
|  3 | Mozambique     |     508 |       258 |
|  4 | American Samoa |      16 |      1684 |
|  5 | Andorra        |      20 |       376 |
|  6 | Angola         |      24 |       244 |
+-----+---------------+---------+-----------+
```

==> I need to get list of phone numbers with its country name and code.

==> Output Example

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| country    | country_code | phone_number |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| Cameroon   | 237          |  6A0311634   |
| Cameroon   | 237          |  697151594   |
| Cameroon   | 237          |  677046616   |
| Ethiopia   | 251          |  924418461   |
| Ethiopia   | 251          |  911168450   |
| Mozambique | 258          |  849181828   |
| Mozambique | 258          |  847651504   |
| Mozambique | 258          |  846565883   |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: You need to normalise your data e.g. by moving the country code in the phone numbers in a separate column. This will be much easier than using [regular expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) within your query which will make the query perform much slower.

Comment: `.. FROM customers JOIN countries ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(phone FROM 2), ')', 1) = phonecode ..`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can express this as:

```
select c.*,
       co.country, substring_index(co.phone, ' ', -1) as phone_number
from customers c left join
     countries co
     on c.phone like concat('(', co.phone, ')%');
```